# How to implement Auto-date formatting functionality in the Lightning JS?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, community, customer-community, lightningjs

would like to show the auto date format like mm/dd/yy.
Here is the example: link [Auto-format Date Input](https://codepen.io/tutsplus/pen/KMWqRr).

so far i was using this code, but this doesn't resolve my problem.

Component

```
 <lightning:input name="customInput" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"  aura:id="test" maxlength="10" onchange="{!c.validateAndReplace}"/>
```

JS

```
validateAndReplace: function (component, event) {
        const input = event.getSource();
        const inputValue = input.get('v.value');
        const validValue = inputValue.replace(/^(\d\d)(\d)$/g,'$1/$2')
            .replace(/^(\d\d\/\d\d)(\d+)$/g,'$1/$2')
            .replace(/[^\d\/]/g,'');
        input.set('v.value', validValue);
    },
```

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Hello Rahul. i was  using below code on onchange funtion in lightning:input tage

validateAndReplace: function (component, event) {
        const input = event.getSource();
        const inputValue = input.get('v.value');
        const validValue = inputValue.replace(/^(\d\d)(\d)$/g,'$1/$2')
            .replace(/^(\d\d\/\d\d)(\d+)$/g,'$1/$2')
            .replace(/[^\d\/]/g,'');
        input.set('v.value', validValue);
    },

Comment: but this doesn't full fill my requirement

Comment: Please add the code in question, use the `{ }` button to format the code.